# Excel VBA: How to return value without making a function that is available in the formula bar

Tags: vba, excel

From what I understand out of subs, functions, and labels the only thing that returns values is functions right?

However when you make a function is will make it available in the spreadsheet when you type = in the formula bar. Is there anyway around this? I don't necessarily want an accessible function, I just want somewhere to stick repetitively used code & return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add The keyword `Private` in your function declaration

```
Private Function DoSomething()
...
End Function
```

The default is `Public`

You can read more on [VBA Functions & Subroutines](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Functions-And-Subroutines.html)